# Search for selection in Vim

Tags: vim, viemu, string-search

I use Vim and Vim plugins for Visual Studio when writing C++. Often, I find myself wanting to search for a string within a function, for example every call to `object->public_member.memberfunc()`.

I know Vim offers a convenient way to search for a single word, by pressing `*` and `#`, and it can also search for typed strings using the ubiquitous slash `/` command. When trying to search for all the instances of a longer string like the one above, it takes a while to re-type after `/`.

Is there a way to search for the selection? For example, highlight with `v`, then copy with `y`, is there a way to paste after `/`? Is there an easier shortcut?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I search for the selected text?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8587136/how-do-i-search-for-the-selected-text)

Comment: There's also the [visual-star-search plugin](https://github.com/bronson/vim-visual-star-search) to do exactly this

Comment: And https://github.com/junegunn/vim-slash which does this plus a few other things.

Answer (score 165, accepted):

Check this Vim tip: [Search for visually selected text](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Search_for_visually_selected_text)

Or you can simply yank the selected text with **y** and go to search mode **/**, then you can paste the last yanked text with **Ctrl+R 0**

Comment: @CMS. Thanks. Great tip! Using :reg to see what's in your registers and then using cntl-R N to get what's in register N is excellent!

Answer (score 114):

## Answer

1. Yank the text you want to search for
2. <kbd>q</kbd><kbd>/</kbd><kbd>p</kbd>
3. <kbd>Enter</kbd>

**Explanation**

`q/` works similarly to vanilla search `/` except you're in command mode so `p` actually does "paste" instead of typing the character `p`. So the above will copy the text you're searching for and paste it into a search.

For more details type `:help q/`

Comment: I like this one, because I find typing <ctrl-r> so unconvenient.

Comment: Excellent! Using emacs in `evil-mode`, this actually works, whereas the accepted answer breaks miserably (probably because of the use of the `Ctrl` key).

Comment: Great for simple strings, but doesn't escape regex special characters, as noted in [this other answer's comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/363111/search-for-selection-in-vim#comment44689091_14747639).

Comment: And you don't even need to yank it. Select it on visual, `q/gvp`, where `gv` stands for last visual selection...

Comment: @nwildner, `q/gvp` doesn't work for me. Could you clarify your suggestion?

Comment: That's what I needed )

Answer (score 40):

Use **q** **/** instead of just **/**. (Same with **q** **:**). Now you can VIM-edit through your command and search history! (Try Ctrl-N and Ctrl-P sometime).

Answer (score 12):

I just learned (through the excellent book *Practical Vim*) that there is a plugin for that.
You can find the [plugin on GitHub](https://github.com/bronson/vim-visual-star-search).

The plugin lets you search for a visual selection with `*` and `#`.

Comment: Note that the other answers don't do any escaping. Using those methods, any selected metacharacters will not be searched for literally, depending on the current `magic` setting. This could even make the search fail for metacharacters that require balancing. The plugin mentioned here will do escaping before searching for the selected text.

Comment: it works, but unfortunately, you cannot use `n` to go to the next found item, while Cory's and CMS's approaches do allow..

Comment: This version of the plugin on github is more recent (https://github.com/bronson/vim-visual-star-search). `n` and `N` work as expected for next and previous.

Comment: I took the liberty of changing the link to the repo to https://github.com/bronson/vim-visual-star-search (as Christian Long already pointed out, this is the more recent version of the plugin). In case anyone is interested, the old link pointed to https://github.com/nelstrom/vim-visual-star-search

Answer (score 3):

You can actually select text visually and press * and # to search for the next occurrence... It will work the same, the only caveat is that:

> Whitespace in the selection matches any whitespace, when searching (searching for "hello world" will also find "hello" at the end of a line, with "world" at the start of the next line).

http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Search_for_visually_selected_text

Comment: for me, selecting text visually then pressing * just extends my visual selection.

Comment: You cannot by default unless you put into vimrc the mapping from the page..

Answer (score 0):

--> if you want to highlight a text occurrences in gvim

1. Select the **text & copy**
2. then **?paste the selected text** (Note: This will not work for insert mode)