# Identifying Identical Blocks of Code

Tags: vim, full-text-search, text-editor, vi

Say I have multiple blocks of the following code in a file (spaces is irrelavent):

```
sdgfsdg dfg
dfgdfgf ddfg
dfgdfgdfg  dfgfdg
```

How do you find/highlight all the occurrences?

What I ideally want to do is to visually select the code block and then press search to find all occurrences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text being searched for is stored in the `/` register.  You can't yank or delete directly into this register, but you can assign to it using `let'.

Try this:

- Use visual mode to highlight the code you want to search for
- Type `"ay` to yank that highlighted selection into register `a`
- Type `:let @/ = @a` to copy register `a` into the search register `/`

At this point, all code matching your selection will be highlighted, and you can navigate through occurrences using n/N just as you would a regular search.

Of course, you can use any temporary register instead of `a`.  And it shouldn't be too difficult to get this command sequence mapped for easy use.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you should look at :
[Search for visually selected text](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Search_for_visually_selected_text)

I've taken it from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/363111/search-for-selection-in-vim)

Comment: Ah, I didn't know about that one.  Would have saved me from writing my own just now.  Ah well.  Makes a lot of sense to copy the visual selection and then use Ctrl-R-" to access it.  I was trying (and I hope I succeeded) to write a function that doesn't depend on the mapping, but it's interesting to see the other way of doing it.

Answer (score 2):

Try this.  Include this script somewhere in your runtimepath (see `:help runtimepath`).  A simple option would be to put it in your vimrc.  Visually select the thing you want to search for and press `,/` (the comma key and then the forward-slash key).

```
" Search for other instances of the current visual range

" This works by:
" <ESC>                Cancel the visual range (it's location is remembered)
" /                    Start the search
" <C-R>=               Insert the result of an expression on
"                      the search line (see :help c_CTRL-R_= )
" GetVisualRange()<CR> Call the function created below
" <CR>                 Run the search
vmap ,/ <ESC>/<C-R>=GetVisualRange()<CR><CR>

" Create the function that extracts the contents of the visual range
function! GetVisualRange()
    " Get the start and end positions of the current range
    let StartPosition = getpos("'<")
    let EndPosition = getpos("'>")

    " Prefix the range with \V to disable "magic"
    " See :help \V
    let VisualRange = '\V'

    " If the start and end of the range are on the same line
    if StartPosition[1] == EndPosition[1]
        " Just extract the relevant part of the line
        let VisualRange .= getline(StartPosition[1])[StartPosition[2]-1:EndPosition[2]-1]
    else
        " Otherwise, get the end of the first line
        let VisualRange .= getline(StartPosition[1])[StartPosition[2]-1:]
        " Then the all of the intermediate lines
        for LineNum in range(StartPosition[1]+1, EndPosition[1]-1)
            let VisualRange .= '\n' . getline(LineNum)
        endfor
        " Then the start of the last line
        let VisualRange .= '\n' . getline(EndPosition[1])[:EndPosition[2]-1]
    endif
    " Replace legitimate backslashes with double backslashes to prevent
    " a literal \t being interpreted as a tab
    let VisualRange = substitute(VisualRange, '\\[nV]\@!', '\\\\', "g")

    " Return the result
    return VisualRange

endfunction
```

Answer (score 1):

Quick and dirty partial solution:

```
:set hlsearch
*
```

The `hlsearch` option (on by default in some vim configs, but I always turn it off) makes vim highlight all found instances of the current search.  Pressing `*` in normal mode searches for the word under the cursor.  So this will highlight all instances of the word under the cursor.