# Save selected text (partial line) from Vim

Tags: vim, save, selection

I try to save some selected text (part of a line) from Vim. Here is the line:

> THIS TEST STRING - **SELECTED_TARGET_WORLD**

where the bold represents the select text. I do this:

```
:'<,'> w! test/selected_text
```

but in the file `selected_text` I find the string:

```
THIS TEST STRING - SELECTED_TARGET_WORLD
```

How do I make it save only the selected part of the line?

Comment: possible duplicate of [In vim, how to write a partial line to a file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1953056/in-vim-how-to-write-a-partial-line-to-a-file)

Answer (score 5):

`:[range]w filename` only works with lines so… you have to put the selected text on its own line.

An alternative using `:help :redir`:

```
:'<,'>"ay
:redir filename
:echo @a
:redir END
```

Answer (score 4):

That case isn't documented in the help (`:h :w`) but `:w` handles only line ranges (you would have seen that on a example of multiple lines).

To do what you want, you will have to first paste your selection to a temporary buffer (or on its own line and then put it back in place) and then save that buffer. That can easily be automatized if it's something you're gonna do often.

Comment: It is documented, but it's mixed with the rich history of vi: All Ex commands only work on full line ranges; the visual selection is a Vim extension, and therefore somewhat at odds with the underlying model.

Answer (score 4):

I do it like this, FYR~

Once you've selected partial of your content by "Visual mode", press Ctrl-C to trigger it

```
vmap <C-c> y:new ~/.vimbuf<CR>VGp:x<CR>
```

Comment: I've looked for an answer to this partial line question, and this is the easiest, fastest and most integrated with the vim function that work without weird caveats. Yes, you lose your "previous buffer" shortcut, but it's worth it.

Comment: glad you like this easy approach, a complete Ctrl-C and Ctl-P way for my daily usage, FYI @TroyFletcher
https://github.com/chenkaie/DotFiles/blob/9f61fb619553ef838dba3750861fd1efd56388c8/.vimrc#L470-L483