# How can I search a word after selecting it in visual mode in Vim?

Tags: vim

Suppose I have selected a word in visual mode.
Now I want to search that word in the document.

How can I do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/363111/search-for-selection-in-vim

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Press y (you'll exit from visual mode after that) then press / Ctrl+r then " end hit enter.

You can use it to bind // for this action:

```
:vmap // y/<C-R>"<CR>
```

If you select special chars you better use this

```
:vmap <silent> // y/<C-R>=escape(@", '\\/.*$^~[]')<CR><CR>
```

Comment: This is a quick and dirty fix, but you'll only be able to depend on it for the simplest cases, because Vim's search field treats many characters as special (For example: the `.` character stands for anything, and `<`, `(` and `[` brackets all have special meanings). Handling the special cases requires a little bit of Vimscript, so you're better off installing a plugin as [lucapette](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6870902/vim-editor-how-can-i-search-a-word-after-selecting-it-in-visual-mode-in-vim/6871062#6871062) suggested.

Comment: :vmap <silent> //    y/<C-R>=escape(@", '\\/.*$^~[]')<CR><CR>

Answer (score 7):

If it's just a single word, you don't even have to select it. Just place the cursor on the word and press <kbd>*</kbd> (or <kbd>#</kbd> to search backwards). Note that this search will only match the whole word. To allow a search for `foo` to match `foobar`, use <kbd>g*</kbd> or <kbd>g#</kbd>.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend https://github.com/thinca/vim-visualstar because you can use <kbd>*</kbd> for searching but with some selections you can run into problems.

Comment: I use [visual-star-search](https://github.com/bronson/vim-visual-star-search), which is similar, but seems to achieve the same result with a much simpler implementation.

Comment: Oh @nelstrom nice to see you here! Thank you for pointing me that I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

I have this in my `~/.vimrc`:

```
" Search for visually-selected text, forwards or backwards.
vnoremap <silent> * :<C-U>
  \let old_reg=getreg('"')<Bar>let old_regtype=getregtype('"')<CR>
  \gvy/<C-R><C-R>=substitute(
  \escape(@", '/\.*$^~['), '\_s\+', '\\_s\\+', 'g')<CR><CR>
  \gV:call setreg('"', old_reg, old_regtype)<CR>
vnoremap <silent> # :<C-U>
  \let old_reg=getreg('"')<Bar>let old_regtype=getregtype('"')<CR>
  \gvy?<C-R><C-R>=substitute(
  \escape(@", '?\.*$^~['), '\_s\+', '\\_s\\+', 'g')<CR><CR>
  \gV:call setreg('"', old_reg, old_regtype)<CR>
```