# How do I search for the selected text?

Tags: vim

How do I search for the selected (with `v` and `y`) string? I usually search with  `/`, but I cannot paste the selected string after `/`.

Comment: related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997078/how-to-paste-text-into-vim-command-line

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In insert mode you can use [CTRL-R](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/insert.html#i_CTRL-R) to insert the contents of Vim registers. By default, copied text gets put in the unnamed register `"`, so to insert that text you would type `<C-R>"` in insert mode. The search prompt uses [Command-line mode](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/cmdline.html#Command-line) which has its own
[CTRL-R](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/cmdline.html#c_CTRL-R) that works almost identically to the one in Insert mode.

So if I just yanked the text `foo`, typing `/<C-R>"` would search for the text `foo` once I press enter.

Comment: strictly speaking this is not in insert mode but in command line mode. And about this: [see this other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997078/how-to-paste-text-into-vim-command-line/3997110#3997110) that explains about registers more in depth.

Comment: @Benoit I knew there must be some name for that mode. Updated my answer.

Comment: Just a comment. Pressing Ctrl R showed a " on the command line. I then needed to type " to get the search term...

Answer (score 4):

```
:set hls
:vmap * y:let @/ = @"<CR>
```

- `set hls` (hight light search)
- `v` => `hjkl` (select something)
- press `*`, copy selected text to reg `"`
- set content of reg `/` as `"`
- press `n`/`N` to navigate

Answer (score 2):

I have this mapping defined in my `vimrc`, it maps `*` to defining the search pattern as what is currently highlighted (escaping all potential dangerous characters, and converting a space in what is highlighted to any sequence of spaces)

```
xnoremap * :<C-U>let old_reg=getreg('"')|let old_regtype=getregtype('"')<CR>gvy/<C-R><C-R>=substitute(substitute(escape(@", '/\.*$^~['), '\s\+', '\\s\\+', 'g'), '\_s\+', '\\_s*', 'g')<CR><CR>gV:call setreg('"', old_reg, old_regtype)<CR>:let v:searchforward=1<CR>
```

In order to use it, start visual mode with `v`, and then highlight what you want to search and press `*` not `y`.

Of course you can map `#` to search backwards (exactly the same except that `v:searchforward` should be set to 0.

Comment: That mapping gave an error in nvim ("Undefined variable CR"). I use [this](https://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Search_for_visually_selected_text) from the Vim Wiki instead that makes searching for URLs possible, for example: `vnoremap // y/\V<c-r>=escape(@",'/\')<cr><cr>`

Answer (score 0):

If you only care about searches, you can use the *cheat* method I use. Yank a word via <kbd>v</kbd> or <kbd>y</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd>, then issue the command

```
:%s//XYZ/gc
```

This will search for the last searched word. Then when you find it, it will ask for confirmation to replace with `XYZ`, and all you have to do is hit `q` to quit.

Answer (score 0):

First yank the highlighted text using `y`. Then

- `/`
- `Ctrl + r`
- `"`

Above commands will paste what you have yanked after the /. Then press `ENTER`