# Search with Visual Select in VIM?

Tags: vim

I want to

- Select a word with VISUAL mode
- Press a key to search for the selected word

Comment: Search for the words in the same order as they were selected, as a sentence, or any of the words selected? I.e. selecting `the foo was named bar` and search using it, would only find the same sentence, not sentences containing `the/foo/was/named/bar`?

Comment: @timss: yeah search for exactly what's selected;

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This has been explained in [Search for selection in vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/363111/search-for-selection-in-vim).

1. Select the text using a visual selection, e.g. `v`
2. Yank it, `y`
3. Search, `/`
4. Paste the last yanked text using `<C-r>0` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>r</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd>)
   Actually inserts the content from register 0, see `:h i_ctrl-r` (thanks to [romainl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/546861/romainl) in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16783017/search-from-visual-select-in-vim#comment24185924_16783292))

Another example is using the command line:

1. Select the text using a visual selection, e.g. `v`
2. Yank it, `y`
3. Enter command-line mode with editing an Ex command, `q/`
4. Paste yanked text, `p`, and search by pressing `Enter`

In short: `yq/p<Enter>`

Comment: I can't seem to find what `Ctrl-r 0` really means, except that it pastes the last yanked text. `:h Ctrl-r` tells me that it's related to `redo`, but is that right? Could anyone explain how this works or possibly point me to the right help section if it's not redo?

Comment: In insert mode, `<C-r>0` is used to insert the content of register 0. You can also insert the result of an expression: `<C-r>=2+57<CR>`, `<C-r>=expand('%')`, etc. Read `:h i_ctrl-r`. Note the `i_` for insert mode commands.

Answer (score 4):

Oh, mate, actually you can use the mighty **Visual Search** originated by the author of the book *Practical Vim*. It's very lightweight!

Simply add following stuff into your vimrc,

```
xnoremap * :<C-u>call <SID>VSetSearch()<CR>/<C-R>=@/<CR><CR>
xnoremap # :<C-u>call <SID>VSetSearch()<CR>?<C-R>=@/<CR><CR>

function! s:VSetSearch()
    let temp = @s
    norm! gv"sy
    let @/ = '\V' . substitute(escape(@s, '/\'), '\n', '\\n','g')
    let @s = temp
endfunction
```

Visual select the content you want to do search, then press the **star** key `*`, Voila !

Answer (score 3):

Bairui/Dahu's [SearchParty](https://github.com/dahu/SearchParty) has a couple of nifty mappings that build on the "yank and insert" method but deal cleanly with newlines and such:

```
* Searches for the next occurrence of the currently selected visual text.

# Searches for the prior occurrence of the currently selected visual text.

& Starts a :substitute using the currently selected visual text.
```

If you feel a plugin is overkill, it's easy to pull the relevant line from the script and put it in your `~/.vimrc`.

Answer (score 1):

To search for more than one word at a time, the vim search supports or '\|'.  So to search for dog cat and bird you can:

```
/dog\|cat\|bird
```

or better (exact word match):

```
/\<dog\>\|\<cat\>\|\<bird\>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why @romainl reply is not upvoted more. It is faster, automatically escapes characters that will mess up search, and vanilla vim. Combined with `cgn` followed by `.`, it is a perfect substitute for those that miss `Ctrl-d` in vscode.