# How do you select text in vim?

Tags: vim, textselection

In most text editors, I can select text by clicking and dragging with my mouse, and then using `Ctrl-C` to copy that text, or `Backspace` to delete it.

However, since `vim` runs in the console, if I highlight some text with the mouse, my `vim` commands don't affect what I have selected.

What is the equivalent way to select text in `vim`?

Comment: A [discussion on Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/190896/154666) has been opened in regards to the validity of this question. Please reference that post and discuss before voting to close this question.

Answer (score 167, accepted):

In `vim`, text is selected by entering Visual mode. This can be done in multiple ways.

- <kbd>v</kbd> <sub>(lower case v)</sub> begins regular Visual mode, and works similar to selecting text with a mouse. Use <kbd>h</kbd> and <kbd>l</kbd> to expand the selection left and right to include more words, and use <kbd>j</kbd> and <kbd>k</kbd> to expand the selection to the lines below and above.
- <kbd>V</kbd> <sup>(upper case v)</sup> begins linewise visual mode. This selects entire lines of text at a time. Use <kbd>j</kbd> and <kbd>k</kbd> to expand the selection up and down.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd><sub>(lower case v)</sub> enters block visual mode. This selects text in a block format, allowing you to select parts of multiple lines without including the entire line. Use <kbd>h</kbd><kbd>j</kbd><kbd>k</kbd><kbd>l</kbd> as usual.
- As @FDinoff suggested, if your terminal emulator supports it, you can even specify visual selections with the mouse by enabling mouse input with `:set mouse=a`.

Once you have selected the text you want, you can use all sorts of commands on them. Some of the more useful ones are:

- <kbd>Esc</kbd>ape visual mode
- <kbd>d</kbd>elete the text
- <kbd>y</kbd>ank (copy) the text
- <kbd>p</kbd>aste your clipboard onto the text, replacing it
- <kbd>c</kbd>hange the text, which deletes it and sets your cursor for typing
- <kbd>r</kbd>eplace the text with the next character you type
- <kbd>y</kbd><kbd>q</kbd><kbd>/</kbd><kbd>p</kbd> [search](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10452438/446554) for the text elsewhere in your document

You can learn more about Visual mode by typing `:help v` while inside `vim`.

Comment: Depending on the terminal emulator you could get mouse support in vim if you use `set mouse=a`.

Comment: Thanks @FDinoff, I have added that information to the answer and cited you.

Comment: In the terminal I am using, `Ctrl`+`v` actually pastes text. Is there another way of entering block visual mode?

Comment: @birgersp I’m guessing you’re using Windows? They have [documentation about this exact case](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/customize-settings/actions), just search “vim”. The basic idea is to tell your terminal to behave itself and to stop stealing your ctrl+v.

Answer (score 1):

### Hightlight yanked text

First of all I would like to recommend highlight yanked text:
https://github.com/machakann/vim-highlightedyank  (vim  and neovim)

This is useful because it will give you a visual hint of what you have just copied.

#### For neovim:

```
augroup highlight_yank
    autocmd!
    au TextYankPost * silent! lua vim.highlight.on_yank({higroup="IncSearch", timeout=700})
augroup END
```

### The vim philosophy goes way beond selecting, copying etc.

Start spending more time reading about vim/neovim and you will not going back to any other editor.

#### Nice to meet you dear "text-objects"

- Read more about them [here](https://blog.carbonfive.com/vim-text-objects-the-definitive-guide/)

**Copy a whole paragraph to the clipboard:**

```
"+yip

"+ .................... clipboard register
y ..................... copy
ip .................... inner paragraph
```

**Copy the whole file to the clipboard**

```
:%y+
```

**Test some vim commands from the clipboard**

```
:@+
```

The above command allows you to run functions and vim commands even if did not pasted them into your vimrc, there are some exceptions but in general it will work.

#### You can define your own text-objects

```
" vim line text-objects
xnoremap al :<C-u>norm! 0v$<cr>
xnoremap il :<C-u>norm! _vg_<cr>
onoremap al :norm! val<cr>
onoremap il :norm! vil<cr>
```

So you can use `vil` or `dil`

**Sometimes you don't need to select to copy**
If you wan to copy the second line to the end of the file you can do:

```
:2t$
```

If you want to move lines 4-7 to the beggining of the file you can do:

```
:4,7m0
```

### copy from mark a to mark b:

```
ma .................. mark current line as mark a

Jump to a second place in your file and then

mb .................. mark current line as mark b

finally:

:'a,'by+

from mark a to mark b copy to the clipboard
```

### Diving into advanced vim:

- [What is your most productive shortcut with Vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218390/what-is-your-most-productive-shortcut-with-vim/1220118#1220118)