# VIM - map # (number sign) to "search selected" in visual mode

Tags: vim

I'm struggling to map # to search selected in visual. What I've tried so far was `vnoremap <silent> <#> y<ESC>/^R0<CR>` (**y** ank selected, search **/** from **^R** egister **0** and hit **CR** ), but it does not work. What is the right way to do this?

Comment: Try that without the angle brackets <> around the #.

Comment: See here: [Search for selection in vim](http://stackoverflow.com/q/363111/)

Comment: Looks way too complicated for something that can be achieved with simple keymap. Shouldn't we make things easier (you know, it's the main programmer task in the end of the day :-)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
vnoremap # y/<C-r>0<CR>
```

`#` instead of `<#>`, `<Esc>` is redundant after `y`, and `^R` should be `<C-r>`.