# Remove Shortcut Added by NCrunch from VS

Tags: visual-studio, vsvim

I use the Visual Studio `VsVim` extension, I've recently installed NCrunch which seems to have grabbed the **CTRL+R** shortcut.

How can I 'return' this shortcut to VsVim?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

- Click on the `Options` button.  It is on the bottom right of the editor screen
- Look for <kbd>Ctrl+R</kbd>.  Switch control to VsVim

If <kbd>Ctrl+R</kbd> doesn't appear in that menu please let me know and I'll provide an alternate method

Comment: In the options, it already says that <kbd>Ctrl+R</kbd> is handled by VsVim, but it doesn't seem to actually be the  case.

Comment: @IsaacKleinman hmm, they are likely putting it in a diff group then.  Try the following.  Tools -> Options -> General -> Keyboard.  Type <kbd>Ctrl+R</kbd> into the box at the bottom and see what NCrunch command it is bound to.  Before removing it with the Remove button coul you right down the name and post it back in the comments?

Comment: I'm afraid I removed it before you posted your comment, so I'm not sure which NCrunch command was bound to the shortcut.

Comment: Now that I've removed the Ncrunch binding, <kbd>Ctrl+R</kbd> is working in insert mode but still not working in command mode.

Comment: @IsaacKleinman that isn't uspported in command line mode at the moment

Comment: In light of that, any suggested workarounds for an issue such as this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/363111/758494 ?

Comment: @IsaacKleinman CTRL-R is [now supported](https://github.com/jaredpar/VsVim/issues/551) in command mode.