# How to refer to key combinations in vim keybinding that works on the query line

Tags: vim, key-bindings

I use pandoc markdown in text files and want to automate links that refer to internal textnodes. For example I have a link like `[\%110lund]` going to the word "und" in line 110. To automate the jumping process I defined a keybinding:

```
nnoremap <Leader>l vi[y/<ctrl+r>0<CR>
```

Unfortunately `<ctrl+r>` is written as the query string instead of performed to copy the visual selection.

So my question is how do I have to notate `<ctrl+r>0` at this location so that it is actually performed instead of written out

Comment: I didn't quite get you. do you want to jump to next `[\%110lund]` when you were on the previous one?

Comment: The second answer in this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/363111/search-for-selection-in-vim) is a workaround and probably more straight forward, but still not 100% the answer to the question, so I leave it open. It uses `q/p` instead of `<ctrl+r>0`

Comment: @Kent No, my cursor is within the link and I want to jump to that line by hitting one key. As written in my previouse comment in the end I found a solution, but this solution works around the question how to refer to these multikey actions like `<strg+r>0` at this place in a keybinding, that means when entering the search mode or command mode

Comment: your mapping just try to reach next `\%110lund` . two problems you have:`<ctrl-r>`, not `<ctrl+r>`, and you may want to use `map expr` cannot help further since I still don't understand your requirement.

Comment: still thx. (the + character was just misstyped)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<del>Use <kbd>c</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> instead of <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>.</del>

In order to avoid confusion, I am striking out the incorrect edit that someone else made, rather than reverting it.  In the context of a vim mapping (such as the `:nnoremap` of this question) the following should be typed literally.  For example, `<c-r>` really means 5 characters.

Use `<c-r>` instead of `<ctrl+r>`.

See `:help keycodes` for more options.