# Search for visually selected text with linebreak and spaces

Tags: vim

In the question [Search for selection in vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/363111/search-for-selection-in-vim), the trick to search for visual selection is to yank the selected text and paste it after the search command `/`. But This doesn't seem to work in my special case.

In my case,  there are linebreak and spaces in the selected text, like so:

```
        something\\
    \end{align*}
```

Yanking and pasting the part from `\\` to the end of next line (which is `}`) produced

```
\\^M    \end{align*}
```

But no match was found by searching for this line.

I also tried escaping

```
\\\\^M    \\end{align*}
```

but still no match was found.

Any help? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the following in your ~/.vimrc:

```
" Search for selected text, forwards or backwards.
vnoremap <silent> * :<C-U>
  \let old_reg=getreg('"')<Bar>let old_regtype=getregtype('"')<CR>
  \gvy/<C-R><C-R>=substitute(
  \escape(@", '/\.*$^~['), '\_s\+', '\\_s\\+', 'g')<CR><CR>
  \gV:call setreg('"', old_reg, old_regtype)<CR>
vnoremap <silent> # :<C-U>
  \let old_reg=getreg('"')<Bar>let old_regtype=getregtype('"')<CR>
  \gvy?<C-R><C-R>=substitute(
  \escape(@", '?\.*$^~['), '\_s\+', '\\_s\\+', 'g')<CR><CR>
  \gV:call setreg('"', old_reg, old_regtype)<CR>
```

Now you can use <kbd>*</kbd> to search for the selected text. This was listed [here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Search_for_visually_selected_text) too.

Comment: I'm sorry that I cannot upvote your answer, as more reputation is required for this operation.

Answer (score 2):

My [SearchHighlighting plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4320) provides visual mode `*` and `g*` mappings that handle this in a robust way.

Comment: Thanks. I tried your plugin, but it seems incompatible with my current settings, as many errors are produced after me hitting `*`.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. Have you installed the ingo-library.vim plugin (vimscript #4433) it depends upon? If you would just like a lightweight solution, Zsolt Botykai's answer is fine, too.