# Search for visual selection in vim

Tags: vim

Using `*` works great when I'm just searching for a word, but often I want to search for a phrase or a filename that appears in code, and it would be nice to just visually select the string and be able to hit `*` or `#` to search for it. This turns out to be more complicated than I hoped. I started with this:

```
vnoremap * y/\<<c-r>"<cr>\>
```

But this breaks if my string has a forward slash in it. I tried getting it to automatically replace forward slashes with the `\/` combo, as follows:

```
vnoremap * yo<esc>pV:s-/-\\/-ge<cr>0D"_dd/\<<c-r>"<cr>\>
" y                - yank the text
" o<esc>           - open a new line
" p                - paste the string
" V:s-/-\\/-ge<cr> - replace / with \/
" 0D"_dd           - Grab the string and get rid of the line I just created
" /\<<c-r>"<cr>\>  - Do the search
```

The there are (at least) two problems with this: It won't work if I can't edit the current file, and it blows up if I'm trying to grab text in a comment. When I use `o` on a commented line, the new line starts with a comment which means it won't scoop up the right text when I run `0D`. Is there a way to make this work the way I want?

Comment: This may answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/363125/3368845

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The top answers in the linked question don't do any escaping, although the solution I'm about to give is also present. I use something very similar to this:

https://github.com/nelstrom/vim-visual-star-search

Comment: There are a few options, see Vim Awesome search: [Visual star](http://vimawesome.com/?q=visual%20star)