# how to effeciently search and change a specific text vim

Tags: vim, vscodevim

I am very new to vim and I am using vs code vim extension. I have to frequently replace some words for that I use `*` command example is shown below

```
const FooBar = ()=>{

//some code

}

export default FooBar
```

If I want to change `FooBar` to say `JhonDoe` I go to `FooBar` in normal mode press `*` it takes me to next occourance of `FooBar` in the file I use `ciw` and change the word to `JhonDoe` and now I just have to press `n` to go to next occourance and `.` to change the word if I want to change the word. This is very convinient and gives me a lot of control.

However, I want to do the same thing but I want to change Foo to Pas how can I do that in a similar way. I want someting like I can highlight Foo in visual mode change the word and go to next occurance of Foo, not entire word and press . to change it

I want something similar to what vs code provides in `ctrl + D` shortcut but with better control

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is `gn`, the `gn` search forward for the last used search pattern, like with `n`, and start Visual mode to select the match (details see `:help gn`). For example:

1. use `/Foo` to search `Foo`
2. use `cgn` to change the `Foo` to `Pas`
3. now you can press `n` to go to the next occurrence and `.` to repeat the last `cgn` if you want.

---

Another question is about visual star: What you want is Visual select the `Foo`, then press `*` to start search. Then the rest of the operation is exactly the same as before. This is a frequently duplicated question.

See *vscodevim* included in the question tag, so just setting the `vim.visualstar` option to `true` is enough if you use Vim in VSCode. Otherwise, please see [Search for visually selected text](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Search_for_visually_selected_text) or [SO: Search for selection in Vim](https://stackoverflow.com/q/363111/14395049).

Comment: Note that VSCodeVim doesn't have `gn`, which, sadly, makes the first half of your answer irrelevant for OP.

Comment: @romainl Maybe I didn’t understand what you mean correctly. But I just checked my *vscodevim*, the version of **Vim** extension is `v1.24.3`, and it supports `gn`.

Comment: Searched issue [#1955](https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim/issues/1955) in [VSCodeVim/Vim](https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim), the `gn` feature has been implemented in PR [#2589](https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim/pull/2589). As with all other commands, **vscodevim** may not have the full **Vim** experience.